# How to query database and display on charts.js in django

Tags: python, django, chart.js

Hi I am trying to display all marketplace as label and the quantity of infringements in those marketplace as data on a pie chart. Please help.
marketplace1 - 5
marketplae2 -4
marketplace3 -7

dashboard.html

```
    <!doctype html> <html lang="en">   <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <!-- semantic UI -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.14/semantic.min.css">
        <!--Chart js-->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js" integrity="sha256-Uv9BNBucvCPipKQ2NS9wYpJmi8DTOEfTA/nH2aoJALw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.css" integrity="sha256-aa0xaJgmK/X74WM224KMQeNQC2xYKwlAt08oZqjeF0E=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    
    {% block title %}Dashboard{% endblock title %}
    
    {% block scripts%} <script> $(document).ready(function(){
     
            const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'pie',
            data: {
                labels: [{% for infringement in qs %}'{{infringement.marketplace}}',{% endfor %}],
                datasets: [{
                    label: '% Breakdown',
                    data: [{% for infringement in qs %}{{infringement.id}},{% endfor %}],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    y: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }
            }
        });    
    
    });
    
    
    </script> {% endblock scripts%}
    
    {% block content %} <canvas id="myChart" width="200" height="100"></canvas>


{% endblock %}
```

Views.py

```
   class dashboard(TemplateView):
   template_name = 'base/dashboard.html'
   
   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
      context["qs"] = Infringement.objects.all()
      return context
```

models.py

```
    class Infringement (models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    link = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=250)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    remove = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    infringer = models.ForeignKey(Infringer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    marketplace = models.ForeignKey(Marketplace, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    groups = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=1)
    screenshot = models.ImageField(null=True, default="logo.svg")
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-updated', '-created']
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

The chart loads but not properly. Its not a charts issue. I think the
problem is with my query. Not sure how to adjust it. I have tried looking up queries but have not been successful in implementing. I am new to Django.

Answer (score 0):

Found the way to query

views.py

```
from django.db.models import Count
    def dashboard(request):
        
      mar_count = Marketplace.objects.annotate(infringement_count=Count('infringement'))

        context= {'mar_count': mar_count}
      return render(request, 'base/dashboard.html', context)
```

dashboard.html

```
{% for m in mar_count %}'{{m.infringement_count}}',{% endfor %}
```